# Rails 5 - integration tests NoMethodError: undefined method `signed' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00000006796390>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I've been looking for solution for quite a long time but I can't really understand what the actual problem is. I'm following Ruby On Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and trying to make some integration tests for login. After a few modifications the code in test file looks like this:

```
test 'login without remembering' do
  login_as @user, remember: '1'
  delete logout_path
  login_as @user, remember: '0'
  assert_not session[:user_id].nil?
  assert_nil cookies[:remember_token]
  assert_nil cookies[:user_id]
end

test 'login with remembering' do
  login_as @user, remember: '1'
  assert logged_in?
  assert_not_empty cookies[:remember_token]
  assert_not_empty cookies[:user_id]
  assert session[:user_id].nil?
  assert_equal assigns(:user).remember_token, cookies[:remember_token]
end
```

`logged_in?` method is avaible by `include SessionsHelper` in `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`. It's core part is to find an user:

```
if (user_id = session[:user_id]) # User is not remembered
  @current_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id]) # User is remembered
  user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
  remember_token = cookies[:remember_token]
  (@current_user = user) if user && user.authenticated?(remember_token)
end
```

However, because test cookie jar is `Rack::Test::CookieJar` this simply doesn't work and raises `NoMethodError: undefined method 'signed' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00000006796390>`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690796/setup-cookie-signed-in-rails-5-controller-integration-tests) came in useful and helped me solve the problem. After some time thinking I did that:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Get ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar because Rack::Test::CookieJar
  # doesn't support signed cookies
  def cookies
    cookies = ActionDispatch::Request.new(Rails.application.env_config).cookie_jar
  end

  include SessionsHelper

  def login_as(user, password: 'Password', remember: '0')
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email,
                                          password: password,
                                          remember: remember } }

    # Set cookies manually
    return if remember == '0'
    user = assigns(:user)
    return if user.remember_token.nil?
    cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    cookies.signed[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

However, I still don't understand why it solves my problem and whether it's a good solution. If I don't assign cookie_jar from requested object to cookies variable in `cookies` method, `assert session[:user_id].nil?` fails even though I log in with remembering (for me it means using `cookies` instead of `session`). I'm trying to wrap my head around that but it's beyond my capabilities.

**EDIT:**

It's getting ever weirder. It looks like I get different errors after running tests several times. Some of them just turn up from time to time.

Comment: I can't check your code as you've added lines that aren't in the book itself. What I can help with is a Bitbucket repo with the complete code from the whole tutorial. I added more tests so that part of my repo isn't wholly in line with the book. What errors are you seeing; which tests are failing? If you have a repo, I can pull that down and replicate the error here, perhaps.

Comment: @OnlySteveH, Sorry, I've actually reimplemented login system so that it can remember user on more than one browser. Here's the repo with the code I've posted: https://github.com/CosmicKid/LucidTracker/tree/account-activation It sometimes says that there is a missing template (but it's not really related to what I want to solve now), it also suggests that user is logged in (users_signup_test.rb:29) even though it's not activated (but it's probably caused by manually setting up cookies without checking if it's activated). It also breaks on `assert session[:user_id].nil?` which I've mentioned.

Comment: Nevertheless, what I basically need is to test whether the user is logged in or not. The only thing that makes it hard is that I can't really test `cookies` because `Rack::Test::CookieJar` doesn't have signed method.

Comment: I've pulled that across into c9. The test failed on first running, the line `assert session[:user_id].nil?`. I think that's correct - the session will have an id even if `remember` is set to `'0'`. However, when running the tests again, they're all green. I only got a failure on first running.

Comment: This is odd. I reset the database and verified the same behaviour. The first test run fails at the assertion that there's no `:user_id`. Subsequent test runs are all green. So, there's something intermittent in the code that is causing your tests to behave inconsistently. I'll try to pick through the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. In this case `remember` is set to `'1'`, I've done it in such a way that if you want to be remembered you only need `cookies` and not `session` so I want to make sure that it's `nil`. I've tried to put `assert_empty` but it turns out that `session[:user_id]` returns `nil`... but, as you can see, it happens alternately. Perhaps I'm not doing it the rails way and I should really stick to the tutorial.

Comment: If I remove my `cookies` method it seems to work at least consistently but it still returns `NoMethodError: undefined method `signed' for #<Rack::Test::CookieJar:0x00000006796390>`. I could dispense with it but as for now this is the only way to check if the user is logged in - to look into corresponding cookies.

Comment: I think we need to take this right back to the requirements. What did you add that started failing. Is it the test that's wrong or the code? It seems that there's a very long test with logic within it. That's not where it should be. I'd surmise. Do you have a 'working' git commit that we can roll back to and then add the functionality you want? It seems that the cross-browser thing is the issue. Is this an MVP requirement? Can we park that to a phase 2 release? I think starting again with that functionality and building it steadily might help.

Comment: I believe this is merely caused by broken tests. If you revert to `be9112d7713a6aa96517a4cb184a3a1bdda0025c` in `account-activation`, everything is fine. The next commit adds email activation tests using `logged_in?`. I don't think this method is broken, it works fine when I check it manually in the browser, it only fails during tests and the problem is test cookie jar which doesn't support signed cookies. I was trying to work this around and this eventually caused tests to behave inconsistently.

Comment: This login system is proposed as an exercise in footnotes in rails tutorial. I decided to do that because I wanted to ensure that I understand basics of rails and MVC. Anyway, I'm almost sure that it's not the case. The only difference is in storing user's digests and the part which check if user is logged in is ALMOST the same. If nothing works out I can try to implement the simpler login system from tutorial.

Comment: Here, 'almost' means that I've probably underestimated the power of `session`. Yesterday I fixed logout bug which was caused by resetting session everytime the user logged out - it turns out that it not only deletes user's id but also special token which is passed along with all html requests except `GET`. If it's so important, I probably should rely on it as a storage of user's id and use `cookies` only for remembering user - so the same way it's done in the tutorial. I'll try this out before I decide to change the login system.

Comment: I think your revised approach makes total sense. Using `session` is a good way to store the `logged_in` status. And then you can use cookies just to do the remembering piece. There are other session managers that might do what you're looking for in a clearer fashion. The tutorial uses `BCrypt`; I've done other apps with `devise` which works similarly. That may have an easier way to add the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, none of those modifications solved my problem to be honest, some of my tests started to behave inconsistently.

I've decided to thumb through [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and discovered that instead of trying to replace the default cookie jar in integration test I can simply check `cookies` in helper test. It turns out that in tests for helpers the cookie jar is not `Rack::Test::CookieJar` but `ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar` which is fine and works with `signed` method. For integration tests I simply rely on modified `logged_in?` method which tests only `session[:user_id]` and looks like this:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end
end
```

To ensure that `cookies` works, I created a suitable test for `SessionsHelper` which can be found in rails tutorial.

What is also important is that I underestimated `session`. I've decided to store user's id there and treat it as a main indicator that the user is logged in, thereby using `cookies` only for remembering users. In this way I don't have to worry about testing `cookies` in integration tests which seems to be faulty.

Big thanks to [OnlySteveH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3323478/onlysteveh) who helped me out by asking some useful questions.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted and I was pleased to try and help.